# WiX Uninstall cannot stop application unless elevated

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've created an installer using WiX and if the user tries to uninstall my application whilst it is still open, they should get the dialog which gives them the option to have the uninstaller close the application automatically or leave it running but a restart will be required.

It seems though that with User Account Control on, I need to elevate by running the package with msiexec from an elevated command prompt before this will happen.  If the user is not elevated, the uninstaller will run, they click the Remove icon (which prompts for elevation), but the setup then simply says:

```
"The setup must update files or services that cannot be updated while the system is running. If you choose to continue, a reboot will be required to complete the setup."
```

I'd like them to have the option to close the app even when just uninstalling without having to manually elevate first

Comment: What is displaying that message? AFAIK, that isn't standard in the Windows Installer.

Comment: This message is coming from the Windows Installer, it's not something I've scripted myself.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. It's a "new" message in MSI 4.0. I have a guess at what is wrong now. See answers.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your MSI does not have a [FilesInUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog box nor a [MsiRMFilesInUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog box. Those are "well-known" dialog boxes that the Windows Installer will populate with information when it detects files in use. The WiX toolset should give you those dialogs automatically if you use one of the [standard UIs](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm). Alternatively, you can create your own dialogs.